# Jenkins job dsl causes a branch scan to happen for multibranchPipelineJob jobs on every run even if there are no changes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I think this is related to the "id" field maybe, previously we weren't setting that and had issues where the multibranch job was reindexed all branches as new. That's fixed now but there is another issue.
Every time the job dsl runs it causes a branch scan job to kick off for all of our multibranchPipelineJobs.

Why does this happen ? Is there a way to prevent this ? For a few jobs it's not a big deal but we have almost 200 multibranchPipelineJobs. So this huge branch scan queue builds up every time the seed job is run. Also, according to Cloudbees there is no way to increase the number of scan jobs Jenkins processes at a time. So it always takes forever to burn down.

This is stupid, am I doing something wrong ? This happens even if there are no changes but frankly I don't think it should happen even if there are. I notice if I modify the config of a Jenkins job and save it, it usually just kicks off a branch scan job so maybe this is Jenkins behavior?

It seems like the ugliest way to handle this, but can you have the job dsl kill scan jobs in the queue for jobs it just configured and not affect other scan jobs that aren't related to the seed job run?